# Styling a Calendar View Page

Tags: views, 7, datetime

I can't seem to get any templates to work with my Calendar View Page.

In the view settings, clicking Theme Information reveals some possibles but I've tried them all.

I'm not sure what to name my file to allow it to work as a theme template.

[image]

I'm not sure how to theme this Calendar! I only want to add a custom drop down menu above it!

Comment: Thanks. I changed the settings to Rebuild Theme Directory on each page load while I work. Whooooo, it's been a while since using Drupal and I'm forgetting the basics! Add an answer to this effect and I'll mark you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [clear the cache](http://drupal.org/node/42055) before any templates you add will be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

The one you are looking for it Display output. You can name it as the last entry in that row. and then click the **rescan button** so that it takes your template. the template should be placed in your theme folder.

There is a header variable being printed in there you can place the drop down some where there so that it is displayed in the header